# ActionView Error when deployed to Heroku relating to i18n

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-i18n

Code works in development environment. When deployed to Heroku, logs show error `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method...)`. This is on the `show`, `edit` action and seems to be related to the `i18n` format I am using.

I commented out the code on the view, redeployed app and confirmed it works on Heroku.

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  hello: "Hello world"
  time:
    formats:
      short: '%H:%M'
```

View

```
<li>Players arrive: <span class="float-right"><%= l @schedule.start_time - 30.minutes, format: :short %> am</span></li>
<li>Coin Toss: <span class="float-right"><%= l @schedule.start_time - 20.minutes, format: :short %> am</span></li>
<li>Game Start: <span class="float-right"><%= @schedule.start_time.to_s(:time) %> am</span></li>
<li>Lunch Break: <span class="float-right"><%= l @schedule.start_time + 3.5.hours, format: :short %> pm</span></li>
<li>2nd Innings Start: <span class="float-right"><%= l @schedule.start_time + 4.hours, format: :short %> pm</span></li>
<li>Game End: <span class="float-right"><%= l @schedule.start_time + 7.25.hours, format: :short %> pm</span></li>
```

Heroku Logs

```
2019-04-23T16:43:39.473185+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-04-23T16:43:39.473113 #8] DEBUG -- : [85be5233-b649-40a0-9707-eeaef1773522]   [1m[36mSelection Load (6.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "selections".* FROM "selections" WHERE "selections"."schedule_id" = $1 AND "selections"."user_id" = $2 LIMIT $3[0m  [["schedule_id", 1], ["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-04-23T16:43:39.492684+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-04-23T16:43:39.492587 #8]  INFO -- : [85be5233-b649-40a0-9707-eeaef1773522]   Rendering schedules/show.html.erb within layouts/application
2019-04-23T16:43:39.494351+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-04-23T16:43:39.494284 #8]  INFO -- : [85be5233-b649-40a0-9707-eeaef1773522]   Rendered schedules/partials/_match_centre.html.erb (0.5ms)
2019-04-23T16:43:39.502847+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-04-23T16:43:39.502777 #8]  INFO -- : [85be5233-b649-40a0-9707-eeaef1773522]   Rendered schedules/partials/_run_times.html.erb (8.0ms)
2019-04-23T16:43:39.502959+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-04-23T16:43:39.502898 #8]  INFO -- : [85be5233-b649-40a0-9707-eeaef1773522]   Rendered schedules/show.html.erb within layouts/application (10.2ms)
2019-04-23T16:43:39.503140+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-04-23T16:43:39.503080 #8]  INFO -- : [85be5233-b649-40a0-9707-eeaef1773522] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 51ms (ActiveRecord: 24.6ms)
2019-04-23T16:43:39.503731+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-04-23T16:43:39.503670 #8] FATAL -- : [85be5233-b649-40a0-9707-eeaef1773522]   
2019-04-23T16:43:39.503806+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-04-23T16:43:39.503731 #8] FATAL -- : [85be5233-b649-40a0-9707-eeaef1773522] ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `start_time' for #<Schedule:0x00007fbde401fb68>):
2019-04-23T16:43:39.503974+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-04-23T16:43:39.503913 #8] FATAL -- : [85be5233-b649-40a0-9707-eeaef1773522]     2:   <div class="card-body">
2019-04-23T16:43:39.503977+00:00 app[web.1]: [85be5233-b649-40a0-9707-eeaef1773522]     3:     <h5 class="card-title"><strong>Match Run Times</strong></h5>
2019-04-23T16:43:39.503981+00:00 app[web.1]: [85be5233-b649-40a0-9707-eeaef1773522]     4:     <ul class="card-text">
2019-04-23T16:43:39.503983+00:00 app[web.1]: [85be5233-b649-40a0-9707-eeaef1773522]     5:       <li>Players arrive: <span class="float-right"><%= l @schedule.start_time - 30.minutes, format: :short %> am</span></li>
2019-04-23T16:43:39.503985+00:00 app[web.1]: [85be5233-b649-40a0-9707-eeaef1773522]     6:       <li>Coin Toss: <span class="float-right"><%= l @schedule.start_time - 20.minutes, format: :short %> am</span></li>
2019-04-23T16:43:39.503987+00:00 app[web.1]: [85be5233-b649-40a0-9707-eeaef1773522]     7:       <li>Game Start: <span class="float-right"><%= @schedule.start_time.to_s(:time) %> am</span></li>
2019-04-23T16:43:39.503989+00:00 app[web.1]: [85be5233-b649-40a0-9707-eeaef1773522]     8:       <li>Lunch Break: <span class="float-right"><%= l @schedule.start_time + 3.5.hours, format: :short %> pm</span></li>
2019-04-23T16:43:39.504028+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-04-23T16:43:39.503964 #8] FATAL -- : [85be5233-b649-40a0-9707-eeaef1773522]   
2019-04-23T16:43:39.504098+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-04-23T16:43:39.504039 #8] FATAL -- : [85be5233-b649-40a0-9707-eeaef1773522] app/views/schedules/partials/_run_times.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_schedules_partials__run_times_html_erb__4351229195490545164_70226775711600'
2019-04-23T16:43:39.504101+00:00 app[web.1]: [85be5233-b649-40a0-9707-eeaef1773522] app/views/schedules/show.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_schedules_show_html_erb__4220913006891638050_70226775641260'
```

Comment: You have a no method error `undefined method `start_time'` - if something went wrong with i18n it would not throw that error... And of course, if you comment it out, it works. So did you migrate correctly on heroku? Or it could be something else too

Comment: I had not run my migrations correctly. Thank you for solving my problem!